# synchronizing data on two (or more) computers via USB

Tags: rsync, backup, tar, synchronization, mirror

I use two computers. The data I need, i synchronize through rsync. Typically, when I come to the computer I issue:

`rsync -vuhzrXte ssh from_the_other_computer to_this_computer`

This works and I find it quite reliable.

But would it be possible to achieve the same via USB flash drive (so that I do not have to keep the other computer on when I leave it)?

The question is more complicated because I need to preserve extended file attributes. Of course then I could probably use `tar` which supports extended attributes as well but I am not sure if it would be able to do the same job regarding updating only the files that are necessary (I do not really want to spend 10 minutes unpacking the full tar file and copying it to the destination from a usb flash drive). Also `rsync` is great as it can do quick updates in both directions, I fear `tar` would be quite painful this way.
What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: Obvious approach: Sync one computer to flash drive, put flash drive into other computer, sync from flash drive. If you don't do that immediately: How do you plan to handle conflicts? (The same file was changed both on computer A and computer B, flash drive has version from computer A)?

Comment: @dirkt I believe that `xattrs` support is filesystem dependent, i am not sure that a `fat` formatted flash drive can hold the attributes (maybe I am mistaken). The conflicts, I would like to solve them manually (compare the files and decide).

Comment: Of course, don't format it as FAT - format it with the same filesystem you have on the computers you want to synchronize (ext4, whatever). You won't use this flash drive on windows, so no need to format it as FAT.